# Extend a link with get variables

Tags: php, html, css

I have this link:

```
www.something.com/index.php?page=teams
```

I then have this link:

```
<a href="?profile=5">Profile</a>
```

I want to achieve is this link:

```
www.something.com/index.php?page=teams&profile=5
```

But I get this instead:

```
www.something.com?profile=5
```

The tricky part is that I can't just write the whole "path" like this:

```
<a href="http://www.something.com/index.php?page=teams&profile=5">Profile</a>
```

Because it isn't always on the page 'teams'.

It might be a pretty stupid question, but i can't really figure it out.

Comment: Tell us more about the pages you are making, what does the code look like and how does the PHP look which you are using?

Comment: Firstly, www.something.com?profile=5 this is not valid.. It would at best need to be www.something.com/?profile=5 - from there you could do a mod_rewrite on your apache htaccess to send /?profile=$1 to /index.php?page=teams&profile=$1

Answer (score 0):

You must include the page=teams parameter in the href.

Instead of

```
<a href="?profile=5">Profile</a>
```

Something like

```
<a href="./page=teams&profile=5">Profile</a>
```

If that link is static you must need to update the html file.
But if page=anyvalue then you must generate the href link dynamically in your php code
for example:

```
<a href="<?php echo "./page=$page&profile=5"; ?>"></a>
```

Where $page is the current page, e.g $page="teams"

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can just add it to the query string using [http_build_query](http://php.net/http_build_query):

```
$newQueryString = http_build_query(['profile' => 5] + $_GET);
```

And then output it to your link:

```
<a href="/index.php?<?php echo $newQueryString ?>">Profile</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
echo '<a href="'.{$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']}.{$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']}
.'&profile=5">Profile</a>
```

This makes use of $_SERVER to get the current page name (SCRIPT_NAME) and the existing query string (QUERY_STRING), and then appends "&profile=5" onto the end.

Answer (score 0):

Well i have sort of fixed it.... i created a session called page, so i can access it everywhere. The thing is i can't get the variable `$_GET['page']` because it's inside a included file called search.php, therefore i created the session.. But thanks for you suggestions guys!